# Prothean rifle in Multiplayer

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

If you have the DLC 'From Ashes', is it possible to get the Prothean particle rifle in one of the multiplayer item packs or no?

In other terms, can you get this weapon in the multiplayer?

Also, if you can, is it considered a rare item or a uncommon one?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think is possible by default. However, you might be able to aquire it through a "Commendation Pack", obtainable through their weekend events (like last week's "Operation: Goliath"). Don't count on this though, they said those packs can include one of the CE/singleplayer weapons you couldn't obtain otherwise in multiplayer, but if it includes any non-human stuff... will have to wait for someone finding one and telling us I guess.

Comment: I have received some Geth and Collector weapons in various special packs and via DLC. I don't know about any non-special, purchasable Veteren, etc. packs though.